# How do I integrate MySql to Google Sheets?

Tags: mysql, google-sheets

I made a Google Sheet containing my clients, i change from “I” to “A” ( Inactive / Active ) from time to time, consulting my tables and changing manually… Any way to automate that?

I need to access different tables, and look client by client the ones that are activated and the ones deactivated.
Then, i proceed to the Sheet i created and change the Colum "Status" manually to I or A,

I would like to automate that.

Comment: There is no simple way to do this (perhaps a 3rd party tool?). It would require scripting and the steep learning curve that comes with that.

Comment: I am willing to try anything. A 3rd Party tool, or to learn how to do that myself... Any ideas ?